# Command not found when running remote command over ssh on mac

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, remote-access

I am trying to run:

```
ssh name@serverIP "sudo speedtest-cli"
```

which after I type my password in I get:

```
sudo: speedtest-cli: command not found
```

However if I SSH on that mac, then run `sudo speediest-cli`, it works.

I have tried putting it in a script doing `ssh -t name@serverIP "bash -s" < ./test.sh`, it manages to read the script file ok and connect via ssh but still outputs :

```
sudo: speedtest-cli: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What directory is speedtest-cli located in, and how does that directory get added to your command path?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

`speedtest-cli` is likely in a directory that doesn't get added to your `PATH` when you run a direct command via SSH, but does via shell. To find the full path, run `which speedtest-cli`, which will output a full path, such as `/path/to/speedtest-cli`. You can then use that full path to run the speed test:

```
ssh name@serverIP "sudo /path/to/speedtest-cli"
```

Comment: Great thank you for the quick feedback, that which command is very useful!